# cross referencing table columns

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to select the names from one table column and then ignore if any rows have the same member as the user id in a different column.

for example i would like to select all the "groupNames" from groups then check the "members" column for any members that match the user.

```
members    groupName
mike       test
andy       test
eric       runners
erica      test
```

If the user was "mike", I would like the list to ignore any row that had the "groupName" test as "mike" also has that as a group name and the list should only display runners.

Is this possible? I have tried to research it but not even sure what I need to search for?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select t.*
from groups t
where t.groupName <> (select t2.groupName from groups t2 where t2.members = 'Mike');
```

Comment: hi @Gordon i gave it a go but don't really understand the answer. i assume 't' is the table name? are you trying to create a sql within a sql?